# Viewfinder-like functionality and crop

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas

I'm currently about to build a bookmarklet using Javascript which will have a small window on it containing a rather large image. The user should be able to click and drag in the window to move around the image, then when they click a button, the image is cropped to the size of the view finder and uploaded to a server via Ajax. Any one aware of a way to accomplish this with Javascript while still being able to support IE?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **[Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)**?

**Jcrop** is the quick and easy way to add image cropping functionality to your web application. It combines the ease-of-use of a typical jQuery plugin with a powerful cross-platform DHTML cropping engine that is faithful to familiar desktop graphics applications.

Comment: DHTML? That's some old-school terminology.

Comment: Its just a word used, but this is a jQuery plugin. PS: jQuery is actually DHTML, right?